# Passing integer value from textbox in SQL select statement

Tags: c#, sql, integer, npgsql

I have an integer in a textbox(Integer retrieved from another form using TOstring) I want to use in an sql select statement.
For example, `select * from table where column = textbox`. The problem is, npgsql gives an error saying I'm trying to pass string into integer column. I try to cast(::int) but still got errors.

Any ideas!

Comment: Don't forget to use SQL parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. I called the SQL on tab click event and all worked fine. Datagridview properly filtered out the rows using textbox integer input. –

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
string text = textbox.Text;
int id;
bool isConvertibleToInteger = int.TryParse(text, out id);
```

Please avoid `select *`, instead provide the column names

Comment: Thanks! But even if you use a stored procedure, I need to use the WHERE clause to filter my table using the ID in the textbox. I just tried what you recommended and nothing happens.

Comment: What would be the reason for wrapping this simple SQL in a stored procedure?

Comment: You can search on Internet, there are lot of reasons. Just to start with. Just suppose you want to change the query. Then you will have to make code changes. Same SP can be reused also across other applications also

Comment: NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from central.equipment where emp_id = ' " + textBox4.Text + " ' ", con);            
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);